# Parameter passing issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I have written a function in T-SQL that is supposed to take a string value and return any row with a similar value in the 'Course Taken' column. Here is the function:

```
enter code here
USE [alumni_project1]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Course_Search]    Script Date: 24-Mar-21 7:45:04 PM 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Course_Search]
(
@course varchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM Alumni
    WHERE Course_taken like '%@course%';
```

However, when I try to use the function, it produces no results. This is how I called the function:

```
DECLARE @c  VARCHAR(255)
SET @c = 'comp'
SELECT * FROM dbo.Course_Search(@c)
```

NOTE: If I use a regular SELECT statement, it returns the correct output, which is two rows where Course_taken= 'Computer Science'. How does one solve this issue?

Comment: You have a hard-coded literal in the function. I think you want `like '%' + @course + '%';` Consider that if the search string contains LIKE wildcard characters, you'll need to escape those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'%@course%'` isn't doing what you think it is. It's looking for rows that contain the **literal string** `'@course'` *not* the value in the parameter `@course`. SQL isn't a scripting language, it doesn't take the value of a parameter/variable is inject it into a literal.

You need to concatenate `'%'` either side of the parameter:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Course_Search] (@course varchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM Alumni
    WHERE Course_taken LIKE '%' + @course + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
WHERE Course_taken like '%@course%';
```

Should be like this

```
WHERE Course_taken like '%'+@course+'%';
```